# How to call spinner on every or http request

Tags: angular, typescript, spinner

i'm trying to show a spinner on every route change , like from /dashboard to /dashboard2 , but it only work if i do it from the address bar but not from the component by clicking

> ```js
> > 
> >     import { Component, Input, OnDestroy, Inject, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
> >     import { Router, NavigationStart, NavigationEnd, NavigationCancel, NavigationError } from '@angular/router';
> >     import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
> > 
> >     @Component({
> >       selector: 'app-spinner',
> >       templateUrl: './spinner.component.html',
> >       styleUrls: ['./spinner.component.css'],
> > 
> >       encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
> >     })
> >     export class SpinnerComponent implements OnDestroy {
> > 
> >       public isSpinnerVisible = true;
> > 
> >       @Input() public backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 115, 170, 0.69)';
> > 
> >       constructor(private router: Router, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {
> >         this.router.events.subscribe(
> >           event => {
> >             if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
> >               this.isSpinnerVisible = true;
> >             } else if (event instanceof NavigationEnd || event instanceof NavigationCancel || event instanceof NavigationError) {
> >               this.isSpinnerVisible = false;
> >             }
> >           },
> >           () => {
> >             this.isSpinnerVisible = false;
> >           }
> >         );
> >       }
> > 
> >       ngOnDestroy(): void {
> >         this.isSpinnerVisible = false;
> >       }
> >     }
> > 
> > 
> > 
> >
> ```
>
> ```html
>  //spinner.component.html
> >     <div *ngIf="isSpinnerVisible" class="spinner"></div>
> > 
> >     //app.component.ts
> > 
> >     <router-outlet>
> >         <app-spinner>
> >         </app-spinner>
> >     </router-outlet>
> > 
> >
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find your answer here.
https://firstclassjs.com/display-a-loader-on-every-http-request-using-interceptor-in-angular-7/
I used it, it takes a installation process, but quite effective. Try not pasting the full code.

Activate a loading css before processing a request, and stop it when received back any answer.

The loading html can be something like.

```
<p class="loading" *ngIf="LoadingVar">Loading dots</p>
```

with the css of:

```
body {
  background-color: #47d1da;}
p {
  color: white;
  font: 300 4em/150% Impact;
  text-align: center;}


/* loading dots */

.loading:after {
  content: ' .';
  animation: dots 1s steps(5, end) infinite;}

@keyframes dots {
  0%, 20% {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    text-shadow:
      .25em 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0),
      .5em 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0);}
  40% {
    color: white;
    text-shadow:
      .25em 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0),
      .5em 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0);}
  60% {
    text-shadow:
      .25em 0 0 white,
      .5em 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0);}
  80%, 100% {
    text-shadow:
      .25em 0 0 white,
      .5em 0 0 white;}}
```

in TS

```
sendHTTP(){
  loadingVar = true;
  httpservice(){..}
}
```